# How to achieve exact nanosecond precision using Date API in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

We are trying to get exact nanoSeconds with 9 precision values for capturing Time.

Using Java 8 we can able to achieve as mentioned below.

```
@Test
public void testNanoClock() throws InterruptedException{
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
              .appendInstant(9).toFormatter();
       for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
       final Clock clock = new NanoClock();
       log.info(formatter.format(clock.instant()));
       Thread.sleep(200);
       }
}
```

Overriden `instant` method as below

```
@Override
public Instant instant() {
  return initialInstant.plusNanos(getSystemNanos() - initialNanos);
}
```

And the complete implementation of the class  is given below.

```
public class NanoClock extends Clock {

    private final Clock clock;

    private final long initialNanos;

    private final Instant initialInstant;

    public NanoClock() {
        this(Clock.systemUTC());
    }

    public NanoClock(final Clock clock) {
        this.clock = clock;
        initialInstant = clock.instant();
        initialNanos = getSystemNanos();
    }

    @Override
    public ZoneId getZone() {
        return clock.getZone();
    }

    @Override
    public Clock withZone(ZoneId zone) {
        return new NanoClock(clock.withZone(zone));
    }

    @Override
    public Instant instant() {
        return initialInstant.plusNanos(getSystemNanos() - initialNanos);
    }

    private long getSystemNanos() {
        return System.nanoTime();
    }
}
```

By using above code we are able to achieve time with nanosecond along 9 precision value:

> 2017-10-08T16:45:45.232000378Z

but in this case micro seconds are coming as 0's(zeros).

How can we achieve exact nanoSeconds time along with 9 precision values without 0's(zeros)? how does it workout?

Comment: By the way, Java 9 has a new implementation of `Clock` that does capture the current moment in up to nanosecond resolution. You might want to look at its source code in OpenJDK. Keep in mind that mainstream computing hardware is not equipped with clocks sensitive enough to register nanoseconds accurately, as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

Your code creates a new instance of `NanoClock` within the loop. This resets the `initialInstant` and `initialNanos` each time, thus you never get to see the effect of the nanos. To make this work at all, you need to move the clock outside of the loop, potentially to a static constant.

You should also be aware that over time, this clock may deviate from real time, as `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `System.nanoTime()` are derived from different clock sources in the operating system, and are intended for different purposes (the former is *calendar date/wall time*, the latter is *elapsed time*). As such, you are actually measuring the elapsed time since the clock is created (over the course of a day, there may be some deviation between the two).

Comment: Thanks Stephen for the reply. I am planning to put this code to a production environment into an application server to capture some events at nanosecond level.
Do you suggest that moving the clock initialization outside the for loop should give me a correct result?

or Do you have any other suggestion to capture the time in nanosecond?

Comment: @YerriswamyManchi As said in the answer, `System.nanoTime()` is **not** related to current time. Check the [nanoTime javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29): *"This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and **is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time**."* Anyway, in Java 8, the `Clock` class is limited to millisecond precision. In Java 9, it's using [more precise clocks](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068730), but only if available in the system